# The return of view() in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am just learning Laravel 5.1 framework, I find a puzzling problem.
First, I create a model named 'Page', then I create a controller named 'HomeController', the method code is following:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('home')->withPages(Page::all());
}
```

I cannot find 'withPages()' function, so I find helper function view() return \Illuminate\View\View, so I find 'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php', there is a "__call()", so I get it.
But I try to delete this function, my site is still normal.
did I find the wrong place? I am very puzzled.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The `withPages()` function isn't a real function and is artificially called using the `__call()` magic method as you already pointed out. Why are you wanting to delete that?

Comment: Additional to Wader's comment: You may use models to interact with database Tables.  You can pass those information to the view afterwards.

For more information about models: [Eloquent Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#introduction)

Comment: I just want to test it! Now I find the correct answer by Nick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... there is a "__call()", so I get it. But I try to delete this function, my site is still normal. did I find the wrong place? I am very puzzled.

Probably.

Laravel 'compiles' all it's core classes into a single file as a performance optimisation.

Try running `php artisan clear-compiled` and your site should start failing.

Comment: You solved my confusion. Thank you very much. I am very surprised this feature. How does Laravel 'compiles' all it's core classws into a single file ? is there any material or theory about it ?

Comment: @xiangfeiai [OptimizeCommand](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/OptimizeCommand.php) generates the compiled file. `bootstrap/autoload.php` is where the framework loads the compiled file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `withPages` method, you need to have a variable `$pages` set in the method.

So your method would look like:

```
public function index()
{
    pages = Page::all();
    return view('home')->withPages($pages);
}
```

Other two options:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('home')->with('pages', Page::all());
}
```

or

```
public function index()
{
    pages = Page::all();
    return view('home')->with(compact('pages));
}
```

You can use any of these methods.

Comment: As far as I understand you don't need a `$pages` variable. With the part after `->with` you just define how the variable is named inside your view.

Comment: @J.Eggerstedt Yes you are right. There are three options in this case. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it -

```
public function index()
{
   return view()->with('pages', Page::all());
}
```